# run JavaScript code from code behind into updatePanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this code on the `OnClick` event of a `Button`:

```
if (true) {
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "", "show_modal('true');", true);
} else {
  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(UpdatePanel1.GetType(), "", "show_modal();", true);
}
```

And I define the Button as a trigger for an `UpdatePanel`:

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEdit" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

The function `show_modal` is located into a `.js` file which is included into the ASP page.

How can I make this script works?

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341623/asp-net-updatepanel-in-gridview-jquery-datepicker/3341741#3341741   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890391/asp-net-web-application-jquery-photoviewer-and-ajaxical-update/13890462#13890462    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856717/jquery-accordion-not-re-initiating-after-an-asp-net-postback/13856997#13856997

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864398/javascript-code-inside-updatepanel) - [other similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487269/registering-a-dynamic-javascript-after-an-updatepanels-update) - [and other similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844061/running-javascript-after-update-panel-refresh)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`. Use `ScriptManager1.RegisterStartupScript` instead. Where "ScriptManager1" is the name of your ScriptManager control.

Comment: It's not `ScriptManager1`, it's just `ScriptManager`. `RegisterStartupScript` is a shared function (ie: a class method, not an instance one) of `ScriptManager` class.

Comment: What about when you need to write a generic method that would run on any page? http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/03/03/run-javascript-from-both-full-and-partial-asp-net-postback/